# how to really include html codes inside php

Tags: php, html, css

theres something i would like to try and has to do with including html on php, my code would be like this.

```
<?php
foreach($element as $data)
{
    <div class="view">
    echo $data;
    </div>
}
?>
```

that would be just an example, of course it will give me error like  not expected error.

i just would like to make a this function for each element in array thats in $element but it has to be repeated with the class on css style. how to do?

sorry im new at php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Alternatively](http://php.net/alternative_syntax)

```
<?php foreach ($element as $data) : ?>
<div class="view">
    <?= htmlspecialchars($data) ?>
</div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: what is that htmlspecialchars?

Comment: @nosthertus http://php.net/htmlspecialchars. It's primarily a safeguard against XSS (potentially malicious HTML code)

Comment: If your data has HTML characters in it (like angle brackets, ampersands, tags) they'll render as plaintext instead of as potentially dangerous HTML.

Comment: +1 for more elegant script and showing me how to protect it, will approve it when i get the permission for it

Comment: @nosthertus of course, if your `$data` string contained valid HTML that you wanted to render as actual elements, you would omit `htmlspecialchars`

Answer (score 1):

Two way is there

```
<?php foreach($element as $data) { ?>
  <div class="view">
   <?php echo $data; ?>
  </div>
<?php } ?>
```

OR

```
<?php foreach($element as $data) { 
  echo '<div class="view">';
    echo $data;
  echo '</div>';
  } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
foreach($element as $data){
    echo "<div class='view'>";
    echo $data;
    echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

OR:

```
<?php foreach($element as $data){?>
     <div class='view'>
        <?php echo $data; ?>
     </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
<?php foreach($element as $data){ ?>
  <div class="view">
   <?php echo $data; ?>
  </div>
<?php } ?>
```